# Non-trivial explicit example of a flat connection

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

We all know that the exterior derivative on the trivial bundle forms an example of a flat connection. Can anyone provide an explicit example of a flat connection that is not just the exterior derivative?

I am well aware that this is very likely a trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want a [flat torus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Flat_torus);  or even more simply a cylinder.